# View not being generated based on model properties

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a custom model like so:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Property One")]
    string PropertyOne { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Property Two")]
    string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

When I create a new strongly-typed view based on this model I get the following:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

If I take out the `DisplayName` attribute it still doesn't work. I have also noticed if I change a model and re-create a view based on that model it doesn't take into account the new changes. It's almost like VS is caching the model somewhere and the only way to get it to update is to close/re-open the solution and then create the view.

The `LogOnModel` in the `AccountModels.cs` file that is created by default is practically the same (only it has less properties) and that works fine. Am I maybe missing something in the way I am defining my model? Can't quite seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

**Edit**

Also noticed as well if I try to manually enter the view markup e.g.

```
<%@ Page ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MySite.Models.ViewModel>" %>

...

<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyOne) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PropertyOne)%>
   <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyOne)%>
</div>
```

I get a compiler error `CS1061: 'MySite.Models.ViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyOne'`.

The conclusion I am coming to at the moment is Visual Studio is really buggy around this area. I am on the latest version (*9.0.30729.1 SP*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.....Nope wait, scratch that. It's my brain that's buggy, I copied and pasted the properties from an interface to save myself some typing and just noticed I forgot to set them to `public`.

Will leave this up incase someone ever comes across the same problem as it wasn't exactly obvious and took me a good while (long enough that I had to post on here!) to figure out what was going on.